# Restoring VD on Perc 6

Tags: raid, data-recovery, dell-perc

PowerEdge server with PERC 6 RAID, two VD, RAID 1 with two drives (mirroring) on each.

System went down and when it came back up the four drive status lights all showed green, but a message was displayed about VD 1 missing.

I entered the RAID configuration utility and physical drive 3 was missing, no errors, just no longer recognized, and the VD 1 was indeed missing, not referenced at all.

I rebooted the system and the LED for drive 3 started flashing amber.

The machine boots off of VD 0, but as expected none of the VMs are found as they were all stored on VD 1.

When I put in a new SAS drive, how do I rebuild VD 1 from the mirror on physical disk 4 when the PERC does not recognize that the VD even exists?

Comment: Do you see the physical disks? Did you try to import foreign configuration?

Comment: I see one of the physical disks. There is no foreign configuration available. Looks like the VD was completely lost so I'll have to restore from backup.